# Custom keyboard iphone , having problem with backspace button in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Check this code (My Custom Keyboard):

```
-(IBAction) updateTextBackSpace:(id)sender
{
    if([txtview.text length]>0)
    {
        NSString *deletedLastCharString = [txtview.text substringToIndex:([txtview.text length]-1)];
        [txtview setText:deletedLastCharString];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

The thing is that I can't figure out how to change this code so that. I can erase any text in any give line at the cursor, the backspace starts to erase from end of the line. I should be able to erase(backspace) from the cursor location.

Comment: Do you have custom keyboard? Handling all events manually?

Comment: did you solve your problem ? because i still have some errors !!! like you and doesn't work . :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this

```
NSString *deletedLastCharString = [txtview.text substringToIndex:([txtview.text length]-1)];
```

with

```
NSRange range  = [txtview selectedRange];
NSString *deletedLastCharString = [txtview.text substringToIndex:([range.location]-1)];
```

Comment: The code looks good .. But I am getting an error : Expected ':' before ']' token . 
Sorry for the noobness

Comment: Hey I edited that to (range.location) instead of [range.location] .
It worked but it is clearing the text which 'after' the cursor also.
If i wanted edit ABCD EFG and i place cursor at D and hit the backspace it's eating the remaining EFG so the output is :ABC 
where I want as : ABC EFG .
Thanks Mihir.

Comment: try using 
[txtview.text substringToIndex:([txtview.text length] - [range.location]-1)];

It should work...

Comment: Tried the above . It gives error as Expected ':' before ']' token .
and when I change [range.location] in your code to (range.location)
then the code runs but crashes.Thanks for helping . What should I do ?

Comment: Previous one was right... but there is some logical error... please put some more code...

Comment: did you solve your problem ? because i still have some errors !!! like you and doesn't work . :(